# cannot read properties of undefined reading subscribe testing jasmine angular

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-test, angular-testing-library

Hi I trying to test http request but , when I call a function in the ngOnInit it show me that message "cannot read properties of undefined"
can somebody help me?

this is my test

````
  it('xxxx', () => {
    userServiceSpy.getUser.and.returnValue(of());
    const spygetUserTwo = spyOn(
      component,
      'getUserTwo'
    ).and.callThrough();
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(spygetUserTwo).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

The component

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getUserTwo();
  }

  getUserTwo() {
    this.userService.getUser().subscribe(
      (val: any) => {
        console.log('xxx', val);
        this.user = val;
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log('err', err);
      }
    );
  }
```
````

Answer (score 0):

I bet you the issue is that you're calling `fixture.detectChanges()` first before calling `component.ngOnInit()`.

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Component);
component = fixture.componentInstance;
fixture.detectChanges(); // Remove this line
```

The first `fixture.detectChanges()` you call is when `ngOnInit` is called and since you have not mocked `this.userService.getUser()` before this `fixture.detectChanges()`, you get that issue of cannot read property of undefined.

Comment: Hi,so, every time i call fixture.detectChanges(), the lifecycle is executed?

Comment: Isn't it best practice to place it beforeeach?

Comment: Hello, not every time. The first time. Every time after the first time, the HTML just gets updated with the new properties.

Comment: It could be best practice to place it `beforeEach` so make sure everything in the `ngOnInit` is mocked properly before this `fixture.detectChanges()` or else you will have issues like your question.

Comment: Hi,so, every time i call fixture.detectChanges(), the lifecycle is executed?

Comment: The `ngOnInit` lifecycle is not executed on every `fixture.detectChanges()`. The `ngOnInit` lifecycle is executed on the FIRST `fixture.detectChanges()`.

Comment: Hi, So , for example If my ngOninit call a api for get a user, in my test how could I test that?  making a spyService before fixture.detectChanges() :? ``

Comment: That's correct, make the spy return something before the first `fixture.detectChanges().`